# How to change axis scale in python?

Tags: python, graph

More specifically how do I change it to work like this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zff7.png) ? I've tried using plt.yscale() but to no avail as it only allows certain set values and I didn't get very far with using plt.axis. This code is a simple attempt at a linear regression with the values shown below, my coefficients (for a function A+Bx) were A=38.99 and B=2.055

```
X=np.array([2,4,6,8,10])
Y=np.array([42.0,48.4,51.3,56.3,58.6])
A, B=P.polyfit(X,Y,1)


plt.plot(X,Y,'o')
plt.plot(X,A+B*X)
plt.yscale('linear')
plt.show()
```

And my graph comes out looking like this:[graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPNz4.png) Which isn't wrong but I got curious on how to make it look like the one above and just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Matplotlib's Object-Oriented API.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline # only needed if running from a Jupiter Notebook

import numpy as np

X = np.array([2,4,6,8,10])
Y = np.array([42.0,48.4,51.3,56.3,58.6])
A, B = np.polyfit(X,Y,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(X, Y, 'o')
ax.plot(X, B+A*X)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.FixedLocator([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.FixedLocator([40, 50, 60]))

ax.set(xlim=[0, 11], ylim=[40, 60], xlabel=r'Mass (kg) $->$', ylabel=r'Length (cm) $->$');
```

Comment: @eyadmardini: are you saying you only see one line on the graph?  Because I get two lines on the graph so not sure what the difference is???